# Minecraft: How Does One Add An MCEdit Plugin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mcedit

I know that this question has kinda been asked before, but I look into my folder and all I see is "mcedit.exe", "MCEdit User Data", and "MCEdit 2 Files". I found a folder called "plugins" in one of the files, but when I put my downloaded filter in the "plugins" folder, nothing happens in MCEdit. I look everywhere for the right file to put it in, but I get nothing. Can anyone help? I asked this same question on the Minecraft forums, but no one answered.

Comment: It sounds like you're using MCEdit 2, which isn't really ready for general use and is incompatible with old filters. For now, you should download [MCEdit Unified](http://www.mcedit-unified.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MCEdit 2.0, which you appear to be using, isn't ready for general use and is incompatible with all old filters. For now you should be using [MCEdit Unified](http://www.mcedit-unified.net/), which is still compatible with old plugins and regularly updated.

---

Once you've installed and opened MCEdit Unified, you should see a main menu which has a <kbd>Config Files</kbd> button:

[image: Config Files button]

Clicking this will bring you to a folder, from which you'll be able to see your `Filters` folder, where you should place your filter files:

[image: Filters folder]

Answer (score 1):

its possible that file doesnt work and recommend downloading a mod version of it if it doesn't have one then i would download the older version as colorfusion said